# How do I implement Sequence (to allow Swift's for-in syntax) from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm writing an API in Objective-C and would like it to play nicely in Swift. I'm having trouble getting "for..in" syntax working though. I think I need to implement the `Sequence` protocol, but I can't find any examples doing this from Objective-C. Just referencing `Sequence` gives me `error: no type or protocol named 'Sequence'`. Is there a special `#import` to get access to it or something?

I tried implementing the NSFastEnumeration protocol, thinking maybe it'd magically convert to `Sequence` in Swift, but that didn't work.

```
///// Obj-C Code
@interface Foo : NSObject<NSFastEnumeration>
...
@end

///// Swift Code
var foo: Foo = Foo()

// ERROR: Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
for y in foo {
    print("Got a y.")
}
```

**EDIT**: It looks like inheriting from NSEnumerator gets me closer, but doesn't quite work either:

```
///// Obj-C Code
@interface Foo : NSEnumerator<NSString *>
...
@end

///// Swift Code
// ERROR: 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') is not convertible to 'String'
for y: String in foo {
    print("Got \(y)")
}
```

**EDIT 2:** I still don't have a good solution and have logged a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2801

Answer (score 2):

The Swift extension of Foundation includes some support for making classes that adopt `NSFastEnumeration` also support the Swift `Sequence` protocol... but not automatically.

One way to do it is to extend your ObjC type in Swift and pass through to the `NSFastEnumerationIterator` type:

```
extension Foo: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

`NSFastEnumerationIterator` (and all forms of ObjC enumeration) are type erasing, though, so they don't provide any insight on the element type you're iterating through. That means that you can do this (after adding the above extension):

```
var foo: Foo = Foo()
for y in foo {
    print("Got a y.")
}
```

... but the static type of `y` is always `Any`. If you want typed access to the members of `foo`, you'll need a cast or a filtered loop:

```
for y in foo where y is String {
    print("Got \(y)")
}
```

---

<sup>Sadly, if your class adopts ObjC generics, there doesn't seem to be a way to make this work — you'll get an error *"Extension of a generic Objective-C class cannot access the class's generic parameters at runtime"*, even if you adopt the runtime type introspection method(s) in [SE-0057](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0057-importing-objc-generics.md). For non-generic ObjC classes you're good, though.</sup>

Comment: This is not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks! :-)

Comment: Although...  It looks like: 1) My second attempt (Deriving from NSEnumerator) works as well as the "extension Foo: Sequence" approach.  2) the "where y is String" trick doesn't seem to work.  I can't access String methods on 'y' and I get "'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') is not convertible to 'String' if I do "let x: String = y" or similar.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't derive from `NSEnumerator`. That's a class responsible for iterating through some other object's sequence, not a sequence itself. (Other stuff might break as a result.) A better option might be for your class to provide an `objectEnumerator()` method the way Foundation collections do. Then you can do `for x in foo.objectEnumerator()`. (2. I'll follow up on later...)